# CGContextDrawPDFPage locks and doesn't return (endless loop)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
CGContextRef imageContext =
            CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, width, height, 8, width*4, colourSpace,
                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);

CGContextDrawPDFPage( imageContext, page1 );
```

This code works fine in another project. But when I try to use it in another CGContextDrawPDFPage get stuck in an endless loop. I see in Instruments that syscall_thread_switch and _spin_lock is called in the loop.

Tried to call this in both main thread and a background thread. (Original app uses this in a background thread)

Has anyone else run in to this issue?

Comment: In my case, I ran into deadlock drawing a PDF page in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7.  In my case, it was a wait trap iside of CGFontCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to instance an UILabel with the custom font, before drawing, to get it working.